# simple php PDO Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This may be really simple issue, but I can't find solution.
If I have

```
$query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM dbName.users");
```

everything works fine, but without dbName it cause error:

> SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected.

Here is the code

```
$Host     = "localhost";
$Name     = "test";
$User     = "test";
$Password = "";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$Host;dbName=$Name", $User, $Password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM users");
    while($r = $query->fetch()){
        echo $r['login']." ".$r['pass']."<br>";
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Does anyone knows, why it works only with dbName before table name? How can i fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: So when you don't include the databases name it tells you that you have no database selected?

Comment: It looks like you're already specifying a database in your connection string. Is this the actual code you're using?

Comment: yup, when I don't include the database name it tells me I have no db selected. When I do "SELECT * FROM $Name.users" it works, but is there a way to avoid writing over and over again the db name? Can it works only with table name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem.

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$Host;dbName=$Name", $User, $Password);
//                            use dbname instead
```

Apparently the `dbName` in your DSN string is case sensitive. It should be `dbname`. After I changed that it worked.

---

Just FYI for anyone else who happens upon this, I messed with it a bit more, and it looks like all of the parameter names in the DSN seem to be case sensitive, (and I was testing this on Windows, where some things aren't.) Better just do it like it looks in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php).